# I want to use year picker in JSP

Tags: jsp

I want to use year picker in JSP like this.

[Year Picker Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xwhr.png)

But I cannot find wellformed year picker widget(made by js).

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

how about bootstrap-datepicker?

[bootstrap-datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)